# Series Expansion

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

*An old problem from Whittaker and Watson I'm having issues with. Any guidance would be appreciated*.

Show that the function
$$
f(x)=\int_0^\infty \left\{ \log u +\log\left(\frac{1}{1-e^{-u}} \right) \right\}\frac{du}{u}e^{-xu}
$$
has the asymptotic expansion
$$
f(x)\sim\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{B_1}{2^2x^2}+\frac{B_3}{4^2x^4}-\frac{B_5}{6^2x^6}+\ldots,
$$
where $B_1, B_3, \ldots$ are Bernoulli's numbers.

Show also that $f(x)$ can be developed as an absolutely convergent series of the form
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{c_k}{(x+1)(x+2)\ldots(x+k)}.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that:
$$\frac{d}{du} \left\{ \ln u + \ln \left( \frac{1}{1- e^{-u}}\right) \right\} = \frac{1}{u} - \frac{1}{e^u - 1} = -\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{B_n u^{n-1}}{n!}$$
then:
$$\ln u + \ln \left( \frac{1}{1- e^{-u}}\right) = -\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{B_n}{n! \cdot n} u^n $$

so we can rewrite the integral as:
$$-\int_0^{+\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{B_n}{n! \cdot n} u^n  \cdot \frac{e^{-xu}}{u} \, du = - \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{B_n}{n! \cdot n} \cdot \frac{(n-1)!}{x^n} = - \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{B_n}{n^2 x^n}$$
In other words it's equal to:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2x} - \frac{B_2}{2^2 \cdot x^2} + \frac{B_4}{4^2 \cdot x^4} - \ldots$$

I've used the same notation for Bernoulli numbers as it is at [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html).

Comment: Much appreciated. If you have any ideas on the second part of the problem I'd be grateful as well.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the second part of the question. Performing the change of integration variables from $u$ to $t$ via $u =  - \log (1 - t)$ yields
$$
f(x) = \int_0^1 {\frac{1}{{ - (1 - t)\log (1 - t)}}\log \left( {\frac{{ - \log (1 - t)}}{t}} \right)(1 - t)^x {\rm d}t} ,
$$
provided $\operatorname{Re}(x)>0$. We have the Maclaurin series expansion
$$
\frac{1}{{ - (1 - t)\log (1 - t)}}\log \left( {\frac{{ - \log (1 - t)}}{t}} \right) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {c_n \frac{{t^{n - 1} }}{{(n - 1)!}}}  = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{{11}}{{24}}\frac{t}{{1!}} + \frac{7}{8}\frac{{t^2 }}{{2!}} +  \ldots ,
$$
which converges absolutely and uniformly on any compact subset of $|t|<1$. Using the beta integral
$$
\int_0^1 {t^{n - 1} (1 - t)^x {\rm d}t}  = (n - 1)!\frac{{\Gamma (x + 1)}}{{\Gamma (x + n + 1)}} = \frac{{(n - 1)!}}{{(x + 1) \cdots (x + n)}},
$$
and term-by-term integration yield the absolutely convergent series
$$
f(x) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{c_n }}{{(x + 1) \cdots (x + n)}}} ,
$$
for $\operatorname{Re}(x)>0$.